# Material Design line breaking rules

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

In the new Material Design Guidelines, there's a paragraph about line breaking (http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#standard-styles-line-breaking-rules-hyphenation).

Does Android's TextView take care of that, or we need to take care of that aspect?

PS: here's the paragraph:
[image]

Comment: Can you add the paragraph please ?

Comment: I've added what the guidelines say. Actually there's only the image I posted, without any additional explanation.

Comment: You do not need to handle this, nor is it really feasible to handle this, in your app.